# Generate Image and PDF with custom fonts using wkhtmltoimage and wkhtmltopdf (Linux centos6 64-bit, hostgator )

Tags: linux, laravel, fonts, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

I am stuck to generate image using **wkhtmltoimage** with my custom fonts.

- OS **Linux CentOs 64-bit**
- `wkhtmltoimage` and `wkhtmltopdf` version is `0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64`

> **Example of Expected Result:**

[image: this is what i am expecting]

> **and My OUTPUT is:**

[image]

You can test [this link](http://test.apiwhatsapp.com/help):

After Googling, I found that by encoding the fonts with **base64** you can get the exact result but after encoding i got success in loading the fonts but still facing problem with **font-weight**

> Expected Result:

[image]

> My Output:

[image]

You can check [this link](http://test.apiwhatsapp.com/helpbase64):

This all works fine on my windows server using **wkhtmltoimage.exe version 0.12.1.2** but i am not being able to solve this issue on my hostgator shared hosting which has **linux CentOs6 64-bit**.

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

wkhtmltoimage requires several font libraries that hostgator obviously don't have. I don't think you can install them on a shared hosting account.